# Skills with different abilities: How to adjudicate what combination to use?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, skills, ability-scores

In the D&D 5e Player’s Handbook, there is a variant option called Skills with Different Abilities:

> Normally, your proficiency in a skill applies only to a specific kind of ability check. Proficiency in Athletics,
>   for example, usually applies to Strength checks. In some situations, though, your proficiency might reasonably apply to a different kind of check. In such cases, the DM might ask for a check using an unusual combination of ability and skill, or you might ask your DM if you can apply a proficiency to a different check.

Essentially, the rules allow for a DM to ask for an ability check but the player can apply a skill, normally associated with a different ability, to the check.

For example, attempting to blend into a crowd by engaging in conversation and acting like you’re meant to be there might call for a Charisma (Stealth) check. So the player would roll a Charisma check and apply their Stealth proficiency - if they have one - to the check.

However, not everything is clear cut, there are often overlapping skills which could equally apply. To use the same example, one could argue that it is not a Charisma (Stealth) check, instead it is a Charisma (Deception) as you’re deceiving the people about your intentions or (Persuasion) as you’re persuading them you’re meant to be there.

Another example, a player wants to parkour their way up to the top of some buildings. One could equally argue that this a Strength (Athletics) check as that is the usual ability associated with climbing or that it is a Dexterity (Athletics) check as you have to be exceptionally precise to quickly grab small ledges so you don’t fall to the ground.

So, my question is, when a player describes an action they want to take, how do you adjudicate which skill and ability to combine to make the check?

---

**Answers must be backed up with your experiences of using this variant rule**

Answer (score 18):

### Ability first - then proficiency

The chapter is in the PHB is entitled [Using Ability Checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores) - not Using Proficiencies.

Which ability applies depends on the 'approach' of the PC to the problem: that is, exactly what is the PC doing. With that firmly in mind, look at what each [ability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#UsingEachAbility) is used for and which of the six is most applicable to the task at hand:

> A Strength check can model any attempt to lift, push, pull, or break something, to force your body through a space, or to otherwise apply brute force to a situation.
>
> Dexterity measures agility, reflexes, and balance.
>
> Constitution measures health, stamina, and vital force.
>
> Intelligence measures mental acuity, accuracy of recall, and the ability to reason.
>
> Wisdom reflects how attuned you are to the world around you and represents perceptiveness and intuition.
>
> Charisma measures your ability to interact effectively with others.

If its an edge case I'll usually let the PC choose - after all they are making the approach so they can tailor it to their particular capabilities.

After deciding that - I throw it to the player to call up any skill or tool proficiency that they can persuade me applies. I don't set too high a bar for this - again they can play to their talents.

For your first example of blending into a crowd: Charisma (Stealth) - yes, Charisma (Deception) - yes, Charisma (Persuasion) - no, it's a personal foible but if you are telling outright lies you are deceiving, not persuading.

For your second example of parkouring up a building: Strength (Athletics) - yes, Dexterity (Athletics) - yes. Also Strength (Acrobatics) - yes, Dexterity (Acrobatics), yes.