# Variant: Skills with Different Abilities confuses me

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

In the 5e PHB, the **Variant: **Skills with Different** Abilities** topic confuses the hell out of me.

> Your DM might call for a Constitution Check... Your DM might allow you to apply your proficiency in Atheletic and ask for a Constitution (Athletics) check... so you apply your proficiency bonus to the Constitution check just as you would normally do for a Strength (Athletics) check.

So does that mean that if I had +4 in Stength, +1 in Constitution and +2 proficiency bonus, then my Atheltics would be +6 with proficiency. If I made a Constituion (Athletics) check, would it be a 1d20 +1(Constituion) +2(Proficiency bonus)?

If so, if I had a +4 Strength, + 1 Charisma and +2 proficiency bonus, then my Intimidation would be +3 with proficency. Does that mean If I made a Strength (Intimidation) check, I would roll 1d20 +4(Strength) +2(Proficency bonus)?

This variant rule confuses me.  I know I don't need to use it but I want to understand it in case I do want use it in the future.

Comment: While it may be hard to identify, is there a particular part which is confusing to you? Knowing what you need clarified is a great help. If this is more a check that you've understood it correctly, knowing what makes you uncertain about your results would also be a great help.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related/useful: [Skills with different abilities: How to adjudicate what combination to use?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/149833/52137)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 23):

*If I made a Strength (Intimidation) check, I would roll 1d20 +4(Strength) +2(Proficency bonus)?*

#### This is correct.

The skill and attribute combinations printed on the character sheet are the *most common* applications of skills that turn up in the game. 99% of the checks you make will use those combinations. *But the rules are the same for different combinations.*

Here are the two relevant rules:

> - To make an ability check, roll a d20 and add the relevant ability modifier.
> - Sometimes, the DM might ask for an ability check using a specific skill — for example, “Make a Wisdom (Perception) check.” At other times, a player might ask the DM if proficiency in a particular skill applies to a check. In either case, proficiency in a skill means an individual can add his or her proficiency bonus to ability checks that involve that skill.

The formula is always the same. *When you are proficient in the skill the DM calls for*, the formula is:

> 1d20 + Ability + Proficency

In this question about hiding a body, I suggest a few alternative skill checks. Maybe seeing other examples can clear things up: [What are the mechanics for hiding something that is not yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/173803/62294):

> In situations where sleight of hand maybe does not fit, such as trying to hide something while not being observed, a DM could consider an Intelligence (Stealth) check:
>
> > [**Intelligence Checks**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Intelligence)
> >
> > An Intelligence check comes into play when you need to draw on *logic, education, memory, or deductive reasoning*. The Arcana, History, Investigation, Nature, and Religion skills reflect aptitude in certain kinds of Intelligence checks.
>
> If we have some time to ourselves to hide something like a large object in a room, I would rule that such a task requires logic and deduction to determine *what makes a good hiding spot for the object*. I would call for an Intelligence based stealth check, Intelligence (Stealth), since logic and deduction, as well as knowledge of stealth, come into play.

Answer (score 8):

First off, remember that…

### There is no such thing as a skill check; there are only ability checks

Skill or tool proficiency simply allows you to add your proficiency bonus to an ability check.

Examples:

If your character is trying to lift a heavy rock, the DM might call for a Strength check. If you have proficiency in Athletics, this will help, since lifting heavy things is part of athletics. You would roll 1d20 +4 (Strength) +2 (Proficiency). We call this a "STR (Athletics) check".

If your character is swimming a long way, the DM might call for a Constitution check and say that proficiency in Athletics (normally a Strength proficiency) will help, since swimming is part of athletics. You would roll 1d20 +1 (Constitution) +2 (Proficiency). This would be a "CON (Athletics) check".

If your character is looming over an NPC, trying to physically intimidate them into doing something, the DM might call for a Strength check with Intimidation (normally a Charisma proficiency). You would roll 1d20 +4 (Strength) +2 (Proficiency), a "STR (Intimidation) check".

### Summary of the variant rule

The GM determines the ability score and considers *all* the proficiencies to see if one or more might apply to this check.